# Use ImageDataGenerator to load images from memory instead of disk for GPU processing

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I am using the ImageDataGenerator to augment images for CNN model training

```
train_data_gen = image_gen_train.flow_from_directory(
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    directory=train_dir, <-- here
    target_size=(IMG_SHAPE,IMG_SHAPE),
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode='sparse',    
)
```

When I train the model, it is the CPU being used, instead of GPU, and a quick search tells me that

> `.flow_from_directory(train_dir`, reads it all in again from the directory as you fit the model. The CPU is used to read in the files from disk. The GPU works but as it has to wait for the next image so it won't work hard. [Link](https://www.kaggle.com/product-feedback/165588#:%7E:text=set%20up%20an-,ImageDataGenerator,-and%20use%20train_generator)
> You need to change your ImageDataGenerator to use the image data you have already read into the images array

How do I then change the images to be fed into the model as an array, instead of from disk?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [buffered prefetching](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images#configure_the_dataset_for_performance) to keep the dataset off-disk into memory while computation and then feed the dataset for model training.

```
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
```

This will keep the dataset in memory after they're loaded off disk during the first epoch of model training and eventually will reduce the model training time.